# structuremap ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<TEvent>>()

Tags: c#, structuremap, domain-events

I am having a rough time implementing eventing in a recent project.

I have verified that  structuremap is scanning properly assemble and adding EventHandlers

```
Scan(cfg =>
            {
               cfg.TheCallingAssembly();
                cfg.IncludeNamespace("ABC.EventHandler");
                cfg.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IHandle<>));

           });

 public class StructureMapEventDispatcher : IEventDispatcher
    {

        public void Dispatch<TEvent>(TEvent eventToDispatch) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
        {

            foreach (var handler in ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<TEvent>>())
            {

                handler.Handle(eventToDispatch);

            }

        }

    }
```

Before I used to fire Event from Domain. Somthing like `Dispatcher.RaiseEvent(new [domainEvent class](x,y,z));`

and  the event will get fired up. I had to change the  design where I am now collectiong events in a collection

```
_domainEvents = new Collection<IDomainEvent>();
```

and then raising it after I have saved the domain to Repository

```
 public static void Raise(ICollection<IDomainEvent> domainEvents)
        {
            foreach (var domainEvent in domainEvents)
            {
                DomainEventDispatcher.Raise(domainEvent);
            }

        }
```

but now

`ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<TEvent>>()`  returns 0 count of handlers

if I watch for

`ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<DomainEventClass>>()`  it returns collection of handlers  properly ( currently I have 2 and it shows 2 count)

... I am assuming this has something to do with  events being raised as of type `IDomainEvent`  instead of actual type and that is making it hard for structuremap to resolve it.

How can I solve this issue?

Regards,

The Mar

--

Edit 1:

I have conformed that struturemap container contains all event handlers scanned from the assembly.

Edit 2

I dont know how to make this question attract more attention. I am adding bounty for a solution to achieve the results desired. If the question is not clear, please ask.

Basically I want the **`ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<TEvent>>()`** to return handlers for `TEvent` where `TEvent` is of Type `IDomainEvent`. Events to be raised are stored in Collection of `IDomainEvent` and raised after the fact that Domain was saved (from service layer).

I am thinking there should be some way to make structuremap know that the event raised as `IDomainEvent` is actually of Type **`DomainEvent`**

var eventsToRaise=  dealer.EventsToRaise();
Adding Information from Debug Window:
[image]

After the events have been raised in the dispatcher window

[image]

Edit 3:
Eventhough eventToRaise shows as "DealerName Changed" and "DealerCommunicationChanged"
typeof(TEvent)  gives Type as Domain.IDomainEvent

I guesss if it is possible to get be able to cast to right type ( from whereever VS watch window is getting info) the problem could get resolved

----- Result---

Both approach worked. I put both approached to 2 other members in my team and we felt that solution without reflection  to be selected as right answer.

Today we will be doing a test with changed implementation and see if there are any issues with this solution in the solution.

I have upvoted  reflection based solution as it is also right answer.

---

Comment: @Still waiting for any suggestions.

Comment: Does `ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandle<IDomainEvent>>()` return the list you're looking for?

Comment: No it returns list with no handlers.

Comment: What happens if you do `cfg.ConnectImplementationsToTypesClosing(typeof(IHandle<IDomainEvent>))` instead during your initialization?

Comment: @arootbeer- I will try and update you in few minutes

Comment: @arootbeer- gives me eror "This scanning convention can only be used with open generic types"

Comment: Okay.  I've done something similar to this in the past, but I don't have StructureMap or .Net in front of me right now.  I'll see if I can work it out and get back with you.

Comment: @arootbeer--I will really appreciate if you can provide me with a solution. I am kind of stuck. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a reflection-based approach, I would recommend using a record to hold onto the type information for you. Something like this:

```
interface IEventRecord
{
    void Dispatch(IEventDispatcher dispatcher);
}

public class EventRecord<TEvent> : IEventRecord where TEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    TEvent theEvent;

    public EventRecord(TEvent theEvent)
    {
        this.theEvent = theEvent;
    }

    public void Dispatch(IEventDispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        dispatcher.Dispatch(theEvent);
    }
}
```

If you find instantiating an event records to be cumbersome, a helper could infer the type parameter like this:

```
public static EventRecord<TEvent> CreateEventRecord<TEvent>(TEvent theEvent) where TEvent : IDomainEvent
{
    return new EventRecord<TEvent>(theEvent);
}
```

Which would allow you to instantiate event records like this:

```
var record = CreateEventRecord(myDomainEvent);
```

Then instead of holding onto a collection of `IDomainEvent`s, hold onto a collection of `IEventRecords` that hold the necessary type data to raise themselves:

```
foreach (var eventRecord in Records)
{
    eventRecord.Dispatch(myDispatcher);
}
```

Comment: Thank  you for code and explanation. I will try implement this and update you

Comment: just a bit confused " eventRecord.Raise(myDispatcher); "  should it be eventRecord.Dispatch(myDispatcher) ?

Comment: @TheMar - yes, it should! Updated.

Comment: @ default.kramer - with th e information in your answer I was able to get the handlers to wor. I am going to try the reflection method just to compare how it works out. I will select the accepted answer soon afterwards.. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

As you say, the problem is that you're asking structure map for all instances of `IHandle<IDomainEvent>` and it has none of those, structuremap has handlers for concrete events. You'd need to construct the type using the actual type of the event and then ask for all handlers of that event:

```
        Type genericHandler = typeof(IHandle<>);
        Type[] typeArgs = { eventToDispatch.GetType() };
        Type neededHandler = genericHandler.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
        var handlers = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances(neededHandler);
```

the problem is that you end up with an IList of objects and you need to cast them to the correct handler type and it get's a bit tricky.... a possible solution is to use reflection to call the `Handle()` method:

```
        var methodInfo = neededHandler.GetMethod("Handle");
        object[] methodArgs = new object[] { eventToDispatch };
        foreach (var h in handlers)
        {
            methodInfo.Invoke(h, methodArgs);
        }
```

Comment: I will  try to apply this as soon as I am back from lunch and update on results.